# unable to verify first certificate nodejs

Tags: node.js, windows

> I want to generate client token from braintree payment gatway in I have used a bit of code to generate tha token...

```
  const gateway = new braintree.BraintreeGateway({
  environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
  merchantId: "process.env.MERCHANTID",
  publicKey: "process.env.PUBLICKEY",
  privateKey: "process.env.PRIVATEKEY",
});

//payment api
export const braintreeToken = async (req, res) => {
  await gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(501).send({ err });
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(response.clientToken);
      console.log(clientToken);
    }
  });
};
```

**But there something by which token is not getting on windows 11 ...may be it is CA root certificate or intermidiet certificate**